# How to include comments for a package with scaladoc?

Tags: scala, scaladoc

So, for `scaladoc`, you can specify comments for a particular component of your code like so:

```
package connector

import java.io.RandomAccessFile;

/** Fs class guides file opening
  *
  */
object fs {
    def printFile(path:String):Unit = {
        val fl = new RandomAccessFile(path, "rw");
        println(fl.readLine());
        println(fl.getFilePointer());
        fl.close();
    }
}
```

However, I don't see where or how you would include a comment that will appear in the index.html generated by scaladoc for the package starting page. How is this done?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a package object (package.scala) and add you documentation there:

```
/**
 * Fs class guides file opening
 */
package object connector {}
```